# How to say "happy cooperation" in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

I want to express the wish for a "joyful and fruitful cooperation" to my German colleague in German.

But it is hard for me to trust Google translate on this task. Can anyone kindly show me how to say "happy cooperation" like a native German? Thanks!

Comment: "Ich freue mich/Wir freuen uns auf eine gute Zusammenarbeit."

Comment: There is also [LEO](http://dict.leo.org/ende/?lang=de&search=cooperation) where you can use the forum to discus certain more complex translations.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can say:

> Ich freue mich auf eine gute und erfolgreiche Zusammenarbeit

or just

> Auf gute und erfolgreiche Zusammenarbeit

You could translate cooperation also with `Kooperation` or `Teamwork`

> Auf eine gute und erfolgreiche Kooperation
>   (Auf ein gutes und erfolgreiches Teamwork) - its not a good solution

Comment: I would not say `Auf ein gutes und erfolgreiches Teamwork`. `Das Teamwork` which would be the article in this case still sounds like a bad mixture of English and German to me and so does the sentence. However it would be grammatically correct.

Comment: yeah it sounds a bit weird and not really correct, but as you said its grammatically correct. I will take it in braces.

Comment: "Teamwork" is actually indefinite, so you should correctly say "Auf gutes und erfolgreiches Teamwork". However, "Teamwork" is a bit inappropriate, as it's an english word and not very formal (if that's relevant to you two) in a german sentence.